# RoR routing error - No route matches [GET] "/articles/8/destroy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am folowing official Rails guide on [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and I am stucked with following error:

**No route matches [GET] "/articles/8/destroy"** when I type path in browser address bar. Clicking on link in template file, doesn't delete article with passed id, just redirect again to it (article).
Rails version is 4.2.1, database is sqlite and working environment is Windows 7.

Destroy method is as follows:

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end
```

Rake routes output is:

```
articles_path       GET     /articles(.:format)             articles#index
                    POST    /articles(.:format)             articles#create
new_article_path    GET     /articles/new(.:format)         articles#new
edit_article_path   GET     /articles/:id/edit(.:format)    articles#edit
article_path        GET     /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#show
                    PATCH   /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#update
                    PUT     /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#update
                    DELETE  /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#destroy
root_path           GET     /                               welcome#index
```

I have checked for typos, even c/p all source, result is same. And ideas?

EDIT: added delete link

Delete link is as follows:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Content of application.html.erb in views/layouts/ is like follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript_include_tag 'default' is changed from 'application' to 'defaul', othervise I got coffeescript error.

Comment: Default conventions in Rails do not allow you to delete a record by entering the URL into the address bar. Can you post your view code that has your "Delete" link?

Comment: @jljohnstone, see edit, You are right, GET is not supposed to call destroy method, forgot to look in routes.

Comment: When you click on your `Delete` link what do you see in the rails server output? There should be some kind of error that can help us understand what is the issue.

Comment: Please post your `default.js` or `default.coffee` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're including the Rails unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery in your application. Otherwise, links created with `method: :delete` won't be handled properly.

This is done via the JavaScript file jquery_ujs which is automatically included into your application's layout (app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) when you generated the application.

Answer (score 2):

### Route not found explanation

Your route says `DELETE /articles/:id(.:format) articles#destroy`. Which means it is expecting the HTTP `DELETE` method.

For `/articles/8/destroy` to work your route should be defined like this:

```
get '/articles/:id/destroy' => 'articles#destroy'
```

However, this **is not** the recommended way to go about it, instead make sure that you set the delete method in [your delete link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

### Manual testing

If you would like to test this manually you could try a tool like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or the chrome plugin [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en).

Both tools will let you specify the HTTP method to use. If you make a direct request via your browser all you are doing is sending a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

when you hit this `/articles/8/destroy` in your url, it is considered as the `get` request as you can see the error.  **No route matches [GET] "/articles/8/destroy"**

but the DESTROY action accepts `delete` request in rails as you can see in the routes as well. now im not sure how you are triggering from the template but it should something like this considering your article is in object `article`

```
  <%= link_to "Delete", article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this line states:

```
DELETE  /articles/:id(.:format)         articles#destroy
```

The server is expecting a `DELETE` request to trigger the `destroy` method in your controller. Something like this, from every guide on rails should do:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy',  @article,  method: :delete, 
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

The `link_to` helper with the `delete` method, creates a hidden form and submit it when clicked.